# Unable to execute user defined function using pyper

Tags: python, r, pyper

I am trying to read data through python in my web app and then analyze it in R. For this I am using pyper to perform the analysis. While creating a function, I get the output only if I write a single statement in function definition. But if I write more than one statement, neither do I get any error nor does my code run.
i.e

```
>>>from pyper import *  
   r('replace<-function(stmt){stmt<-gsub("@(.*?) +","||T|| ",stmt)}')
```

works well enough but

```
>>>r('replace<-function(stmt)  
    {stmt<-gsub("@(.*?) +","||T|| ",stmt)  
     stmt<-gsub("(http://t.co/)[0-9a-zA-Z]*","||U|| ",stmt)}')
```

does not execute. 
 This is the same case with all other functions. I am not able to club all commands within a single block. Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

May be you should call like this:

```
R("""replace<-function(stmt)  
    {stmt<-gsub("@(.*?) +","||T|| ",stmt)  
     stmt<-gsub("(http://t.co/)[0-9a-zA-Z]*","||U|| ",stmt)}""")
```